# Forcing the order of arguments in function generated for a "alias"

Tags: fish

When I create an alias like:
`alias "myA" "PREFIX $argv SUFFIX"`
fish genarates a function with body equivalent to: `"PREFIX SUFFIX $argv`.
Is there a trick/hack/legitimate way to force the shell so that the call `myA 1234` is executed as `PREFIX 1234 SUFFIX`?

I know how to do that by writing a function.  I generate about 15+ of these, on the fly, and the PREFIX, SUFFIX strings keep changing very frequently.  So it is not practical to write a function.

Thanks!

Cheers; 'best,

shankar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have misunderstood what the `alias` command does. It does define a function. But it does not do the transformation you imply. It only appears to do so because you double-quoted the alias definition. Which means that `$argv` is interpolated before the function is created. If, as is likely to be the case, `$argv` is undefined (or the empty array) then `"PREFIX $argv SUFFIX"` is equivalent to `"PREFIX SUFFIX"`.

To answer your question: No, there is no way to do what you want using the `alias` command. Honestly, I think `alias` should never have been added to fish as it isn't needed and simply confuses people migrating from bash where the concept of an "alias" is very different. It's trivial to replace

```
alias myA "PREFIX $argv SUFFIX"
```

with

```
function myA; PREFIX $argv SUFFIX; end
```

Comment: Re: "... alias should never have been ...":  Is there a way to add multiple functions in the same file? I can have multiple aliases in the same file which makes it easy to edit a subset of them together without having to open each file. Is there a way to do that with functions?

Comment: Yes, you can put more than one function definition in the same file; e.g., your *~/.config/fish/config.fish* file. Where did you get the idea that isn't possible? After all, `alias` is just an alternative way to define a function.